# One-To-Many and Many-To-One relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a class Environment that has a list of Video objects (relationship One-To-Many), and in the class Video, i have a relationship with Environment of Many-To-One.

How to express this in Django?

Comment: RTFM: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a foreign key in your model Video this

```
class Video(models.Model):
    environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment)
```

Comment: Ok...so in the class Environment i dont to put anything related to video right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look of [foreignkey in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

A foreign key is a many-to one relationship. In your example, one Environment can have many videos.